# how to get the value from combobox and pass it to the next step?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, combobox

I have written this code :

```
InstalledFontCollection fonts = new InstalledFontCollection();
foreach (FontFamily fnt in fonts.Families)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(fnt.Name);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get the name selected and pass it to my function (instead of predefined Arial font)?

```
Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 60f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the comboBox1.SelectedItem to get the selected value of combobox.

```
 Font font = new Font(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), 60F);
```

Comment: do you mean instad of typing "Arial", i just need to type "comboBox1.Selecteditem"?

Comment: SelectedText is wrong, that will give you the text _highlighted_ by user selection using the mouse.

Comment: for some fonts its giving me an error "Font 'Aharoni' does not support style 'Regular'??!

Comment: @CowBoy: By looking into the error it looks like that selected font does not support the FontStyle.Regular.

Comment: but where doeas this FontStyle.Regular comes from? i was thinking it just prints whatever is chosen in the combobox..!

Comment: @CowBoy: Actually this error has nothing to do with Font selection from combobox. It looks like that you need to set the font style as well (style other than regular which is default value) while setting this 'Aharoni' font. There is a possibility that this font has been designed for special style. You may have to do some google about it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler to the `ComboBox` for `SelectionChangeCommitted`:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Font myFont = new Font(comboBox1.Text, 60f);
    //use the font
}
```

Beware using `SelectedItem`, as it will likely return a reference to the item (a class) and not provide the text in a direct way.  `SelectedValue` is also suspect, because unless you set the `ValueMember` parameter, it might be `null`.

Comment: should i put it under "comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" ?

Comment: The event handler is optional.  If you already have a way to react to user selection, then just use the `comboBox1.Text` parameter to get the font name.

Comment: Updated answer.  It seems `SelectionChangeCommitted` occurs before the text field is updated.  Therefore, the `Text` parameter is one step behind.  So yes, use `SelectedIndexChanged`.  But be aware that that event fires due to programmatic change as well, so you'll get it when you set `comboBox1.SelectedIndex`.